# Get table names from Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

After you have setup your mappings in fluent nhibernate, is there a way of getting the table name for an entity from the class type?

I have read in regular nhiberante you can do something like `cfg.GetClassMapping(typeof (Employee))`. I would like to do the type of thing to retrieve the database table name.

Is this possible as standard or how would I go about this?

Answer (score 14):

The fluent nhibernate way:

```
var userMetadata = sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(SomeEntity)) as NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister;
var cols = userMetadata.KeyColumnNames;
var table = userMetadata.TableName;
```

where sessionFactory is of type ISessionFactory.

Comment: In case anyone else is doing this in VB.NET - it's just a case of altering the casting syntax - DirectCast(sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(SomeEntity)), AbstractEntityPersister).TableName

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have done this at some point:

```
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration fluentConfig = FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Fluently.Configure();
```

Then all you have to do is this:

```
string tableName = fluentConfig.BuildConfiguration().GetClassMapping(typeof (One of your data entities)).Table.Name;
```

Worked great in my implementation of a generic "GetAllItems" routine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm using this to create Full Text Catalogs on M$ Sql Server, using almost same mechanism of FluentNhibernate mapping.

From Configuration I get a list of  persistentClasses

```
this.persistenClasses = configuration.ClassMappings;
```

Next I search through this list to find my persistenClass class by its Generic type of mapping class

```
var genericDefinition = mappingClass.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
var matchedPersistClass = FindPersistedClassFrom(genericDefinition);


        private PersistentClass FindPersistedClassFrom(Type genericDefinition)
        {
            return persistentClasses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EntityName == genericDefinition.FullName);
        }
```

So having persistentClass you easily have access to Table Name, properties, db fields, etc.

```
TableName = matchedPersistClass.Table.Name,
```

Answer (score 0):

`cfg.GetClassMapping(typeof(Employee)).Table.Name` will also work, and seems to be much simpler.