# Get primary key on PostDeleteEventListener

Tags: c#, nhibernate, event-listener

How can I get an entity's primary key value on NHibernate's PostDeleteEventListener? (Also considering the case of composite primary keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you tried something and failed... because, the passed `PostDeleteEvent` object is the answer:

```
public void OnPostDelete(PostDeleteEvent @event)
{
    var id = @event.Id;
    var entity = @event.Entity;
    var state = @event.DeletedState;
    ...
```

And if you'll take a look a the parent `Event` constructor documentation *(`PostDeleteEvent : AbstractPostDatabaseOperationEvent`)*:

```
/// <summary> Constructs an event containing the pertinent information. </summary>
/// <param name="source">The session from which the event originated. </param>
/// <param name="entity">The entity to be invloved in the database operation. </param>
/// <param name="id">The entity id to be invloved in the database operation. </param>
/// <param name="persister">The entity's persister. </param>
protected AbstractPostDatabaseOperationEvent(
   IEventSource source
 , object entity
 , object id
 , IEntityPersister persister)
```

Comment: Thanks, with the `Id` property I could get the ID of the object. If it's not too much to ask, is there a way to get the name of the database table and fields of the primary key?

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9833187/1679310. E.g. `var persister = factory.GetClassMetadata(entityType) as AbstractEntityPersister` with this you can get a lot mapping information